# Node.js + Express: GET-Request returns 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get, http-status-code-404

I got a problem when working with Node.js and Express.
I try to send an ID (basically a random string) from the client side via jQuery to the server. But no matter what I try... it returns a 404 not found.

My client side javascript:

```
$.get('/controller/setclickedplace/' + place.id, function(popupHtml) {
    $('#popup').html(popupHtml);
});
```

My server side app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
```

...

```
var app = express();
```

...

```
var controller = require('./routes/controller');
```

...

```
app.use('/controller', controller);
```

My server side routes/controller.js (router):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

//require controller modules
var googlePlacesController = require('../controller/GooglePlacesController');

//Set clicked places ID
router.get('/setclickedplace/:place_id', googlePlacesController.setClickedPlace);

module.exports = router;
```

My server side controller/GooglePlacesController.js (controller):

```
exports.setClickedPlace = function (req, res, next) {
    var googlePlaceID = res.params.place_id;
    res.render('popup', {place_id: googlePlaceID});
};
```

I have no idea what's wrong there.

Client console says:

`GET http://localhost:3000/controller/setclickedplace/9ac35ce7115b1b4d9f5c3a28c0a2d0774cf36d9d 404 (Not Found)`

Server console says:

`GET /controller/setclickedplace/9ac35ce7115b1b4d9f5c3a28c0a2d0774cf36d9d 404 0.828 ms - 212`

Thanks for your answers.

Greetings
Julian

Comment: post the full code for the node server please

Comment: `router` is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code, I not posted all here

Comment: Does GooglePlacesController.js have a modules.exports statement? it needs to export the function for controller.js to use

Comment: It don't have `module.exports = GooglePlacesController;`, but there is another get function which works and when I'm adding the `module.exports`it still don't work.

Comment: What's the full code for GooglePlacesController.js?

Comment: `var gmClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: '*****GOOGLE-API-KEY*****',
  Promise: Promise
});

// set by client clicked place
exports.setClickedPlace = function (req, res, next) {
  var googlePlaceID = res.params.place_id;
  res.render('popup', {place_id: googlePlaceID});
};`

Comment: Basically it's all. Theres just the Google Places API defined.

Comment: in controller.js what is the output if you console.log the googlePlacesController variable?

Comment: `{ getPlaces: [Function], setClickedPlace: [Function] }`

Comment: The routing looks fine to me. I see two possibilities. 1. You haven't restarted since you last changed the code. 2. You've got a 404 handler route registered before your controller route.

Comment: in the exports.setClickedPlace function, if you console log something does it output when client sends the get request?

Comment: I restarted a lot times since I have nodemon installed. And I think I don't have a 404 handler route registered before my controller route. You mean in app.js or controller.js?

Comment: No it doesn't log anything. Even not a random string.

Comment: well you could try another approach: send a querystring from the client like '/controller/setclickedplace?placeid=' + place.id

and then change your route to just
router.get('/setclickedplace', googlePlacesController.setClickedPlace)

and finally, in the code for that route you will have access to the id via req.query.placeid

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, I found my fault. Look in my GooglePlacesController.js... I wrote `var googlePlaceID = res.params.placeid;` instead of `var googlePlaceID = req.params.placeid;`. So **res** instead of **req**. Thank you for your help :)